# Highcharts Pie Chart turning off data label

Tags: highcharts

I have using the pie chart and im wondering how can I turn off the data labels, the label text that goes out from each slice. And I would still want to have the ability to hover over and see the tooltips etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled:false
            }
        }
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1mmz2pu2/)